Is there any way to specify an IP address while setting authorized domains in firebase console?
While setting authorized domains (i.e. localhost) in firebase console, can we set an IP address, in order to secure our firebase app from being accessed by someone, when developing it. Or are there any other way to secure your api credentials from being used by unauthorized sources.
I want a solution to secure my firebase app.

No, it's not possible. You are responsible for securing your own app using some means other than IP address. Typically that means you correctly integrate Firebase Authentication first, establish correct security rules, and require a user login for all activity. None of your "API credentials" are at risk here. They are essentially public information anyway once you publish your app.
Read:

Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?

